# How to get back information of payment when donate via paypal by credit card?

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I'm developing a donation website like kickstarter , indiegogo , gofundme, crowdonomic,... use donation paypal's service in this url http://ourdreamhomeweddingregistry.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=profilepage&id=310&itemid=0

My trouble is when the donators use their credit card to donate then website didn't get back the payment information from paypal redirect to update new amount in couple's profile. I tested it worked ok with sandbox.paypal.com but when run with real paypal, seem it doesn't work same it done with sandbox.

Please help me a reason for this issue, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you..

Please refer IPN payment notification

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#example_req_resp

IPN is a message service that PayPal uses to notify you about events, such as:
Instant payments, including Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments, and direct credit card payments, and authorizations (which indicate a sale whose payment has not yet been collected)

In your web application, you need to create an IPN listener to capture all the IPN responses from paypal. configure the IPN capture / listner page in the real paypal account settings. Give a try, create a snippet to  capture the response and write it in a notepad / text file. you can see the list of details in it. From that script your functionality to achieve the goal.

Hope it helps.